# using multiple IEnumerable Joins

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

If i have 3 tables. How can i use IEnumerable LINQ Joins to join all 3 tables together? here is my current query and I want to join another IEnumerable called BudgetTargets using the GPRow id = Budgettargets id

```
var rows = _context.GpRows.Join(
            _context.ShopInfos,
            GpRow => GpRow.ShopId,
            ShopInfo => ShopInfo.ShopId,
            (GpRow, ShopInfo) => new{ 
                ShopName = ShopInfo.ShopName,
                State = ShopInfo.State,
                YearMonth = String.Concat(GpRow.Year, GpRow.Month),
                GpRow.Year,
                GpRow.Month,
                GpRow.Id,
                GpRow.ShopId,
                GpRow.PaintSale,
                GpRow.PanelSale,
                GpRow.PartsSale,
                GpRow.OtherSale,
                GpRow.PaintCost,
                GpRow.PanelCost,
                GpRow.PartsCost,
                GpRow.OtherCost,
                GpRow.PanelWages,
                GpRow.PaintWages,
                GpRow.Depreciation,
                GpRow.ForecastedSales,
                GpRow.Expenses
            }
        )
        .Where(GpRow => shopId_Array.Contains(GpRow.ShopId))
        .OrderByDescending(a => a.Year).OrderByDescending(b => b.Month).ThenBy(c => c.State).ThenBy(c => c.ShopName)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: If this is EF I'd suggest looking into using Navigation properties assuming the tables you want to join have proper FKs setup.  That or you might find this easier to write in query syntax, for example `from x in table1 join y in table2 on x.Id equals y.XId join z in table3 on y.Id equals z.YId`

Comment: Thanks Juharr however that join only returns matches I want a left join :(

Comment: @MichaelZerofiveJenkins, please check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq) may be helpful. In case of left join, you probably need to think about `DefaultIfEmpty`.

Comment: @MichaelZerofiveJenkins You should include in your question that you want left joins.  Those are done like this `from x in table1 join y in table2 on x.Id equals y.XId into grp from y in grp.DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: how do I mark your comments as answer Juharr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @juharr's comment. The LINQ query format is sometimes clearer about intent than the fluent API style. Here is how the query would be written.

```
var rows = from GpRow in _context.GpRows
    join ShopInfo in _context.ShopInfos on GpRow.ShopId equals ShopInfo.ShopId
    orderby GpRow.ShopId descending, GpRow.Month descending, ShopInfo.State, ShopInfo.ShopName
    select new { 
        ShopName = ShopInfo.ShopName,
        State = ShopInfo.State,
        YearMonth = String.Concat(GpRow.Year, GpRow.Month),
        GpRow.Year,
        GpRow.Month,
        GpRow.Id,
        GpRow.ShopId,
        GpRow.PaintSale,
        GpRow.PanelSale,
        GpRow.PartsSale,
        GpRow.OtherSale,
        GpRow.PaintCost,
        GpRow.PanelCost,
        GpRow.PartsCost,
        GpRow.OtherCost,
        GpRow.PanelWages,
        GpRow.PaintWages,
        GpRow.Depreciation,
        GpRow.ForecastedSales,
        GpRow.Expenses
    };
```